# Converting strings, based of units in MongoDB field

Tags: json, string, mongodb, parsing, data-conversion

I am using MongoDB to store different values based of units. 
For example I have a speed field:
`"Speed":"1 m/s"`
or 
`"Speed":"1 mph"`
I also have distance field, like this:
`"Distance": "1 ft"`
or 
`"Distance":"1 meter"`
I have about 20 different field types, like speed, distance, power, area, angle, and others I would like to store all the fields of different units types in the same units, so I can compare them. I am not sure if it would be best to do this on input or when I am reading from the database, but either is an option. 
I am planning on storing a field unit type, I.E. this field is a speed, and an equation to get to the base unit, I.E. if the speed field has m/s and the base field in ft/sec multiple by 3.28, but I am not sure how to structure this. So ideally the fields above would be something like:

```
{"Speed":"1 m/s"},
{"Speed":"1 mph"},
{"Distance": "1 ft"},
{"Distance":"1 meter"}
```

Would become

```
{"Speed":{"base(ft/sec)":3.28,"orig_val":1,"orig_unit":"m/s"},
{"Speed":{"base(ft/sec)":1.47,"orig_val":1,"orig_unit":"mph"},
{"Distance":{"base(in)":12,"orig_val":1,"orig_unit":"ft"},
{"Distance":{"base(in)":39.37,"orig_val":1,"orig_unit":"meter"}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts.

Store a specific field as the same unit, irrespective of how you capture - e.g., distance is always stored as feet. The field would be stored as `{ distance_feet: 120 }`.

Store a specific field as it is captured, i.e., a field can be captured with different units. This will have an additional field specifying the "units". For example, `{ distance: 120, units: "feet" }`. In this case, the field units can be either "feet" or "meters" .

In both the cases, the application (or program) logic can take care of the conversion from feet to meters or vice-versa.

An additional field called as "conversion_factor" can be stored in the collection (e.g., for feet and meters conversion, `{ conversion_factor: 3.38084 }` ). This  involves storage of same information in the database many times and with large amount of data this adds to the storage space and memory when data is read - a factor to consider.

What info to store and how depends upon factors:

- What is purpose of this data and how it is used in the application?
- Is it queried? How and in what format? Captured in what format? How
  often? What kind of computations (calculations, comparisons, etc.)
  happen upon this data?

I think the application requirements or functionality should drive how you design the data, not how you have to program it. You should know at this stage what are the important things you will be doing with the data.

> I have about 20 different field types, like speed, distance, power,
>   area, angle, and others I would like to store all the fields of
>   different units types in the same units, so I can compare them.

I think, comparing is a computation and the program can take care of data like "conversion factor" and converting from one unit to another.